# Dropbox iOS Core API - Working with DBRestClient in separate thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox iOS api in an application that need to upload file generated local by the app. When the app generate a file it is inserted in a queue (a separate thread), and I need that DBRestClient send it to Dropbox in background; but unfortunately the DBRestClient need a ViewController delegate (that I haven't in my context; is a generic NSObject class), and when I call the upload file method nothing seem to happen.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call an `uploadFile` method, one of the delegate methods should be called to give you the response:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath from:(NSString*)srcPath 
        metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress 
        forFile:(NSString*)destPath from:(NSString*)srcPath;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;
// [error userInfo] contains the sourcePath
```

Have you implemented these?

If so, there are a few things that might cause your delegate methods to not be called:

1. Your rest client is nil or is being released (e.g., by ARC) prematurely.
2. You're making the call in a background thread that doesn't have a run loop.
3. Your delegate method that should be called back has a typo in it. Unfortunately the SDK doesn't warn you if it can't find a delegate method to call; it just completes without telling anyone.

The second one may be relevant, given your description, in which case this may be helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1

Comment: The second one is my case. Now I call the methods with a NSTimer. Thank you